# WPF, Exception when using a converter for Enum Description

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to build an application using MVVM pattern in WPF. I have the following as part of a view (***FooView***)

```
                        <ComboBox 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Foo}">
                          <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter= {StaticResource EnumDescriptionValueConverter }}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                          </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
```

Where  **EnumDescriptionValueConverter** helps me display the Description attribute on an Enumeration. Here's the convert method I use :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {     
      return ((Enum)value).GetDescription();
    }
```

I then use a Data Template to render this view using this Xaml

```
                  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FooCollection.CollectionView}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                        <local:FooView/>
                      </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                  </ListBox>
```

Where ***FooCollection*** is a FilterObservableCollection. It all works well and displays the Enum description in the combo box as expected.

My aim, is to be able to add and delete items from the FooCollection. However, when I call FooCollection.Remove(aFoo), the  Convert method in **EnumDescriptionValueConverter** is called with an empty string (in place of of the value parameter), which will throw an exception.

Any ideas on why this method is being called with an empty string? Please also provide any suggestion/alternative ways you'd go about implementing this.

Thanks

Comment: This is because the  FilterObservableCollection is two way and when ever the collection modified entire logical tree will get refreshed. one thing you can do is to stop calling the converter if the value is empty or put a value check inside the converter

Comment: @PrajeeshTS Thanks for that comment, however, I would like to keep the convert method quiet generic (value could be any object), so the callers responsible for passing in an Enum. The Itemsource that I bind to it (Foos) is an array of Enum, so I am not sure why the converter gets called with an empty string.